# Testing marginal homogeniety with multivariate outcomes and matched pairs

Tags: agreement-statistics, marginal-distribution, matching

Suppose I have 20 people matched in 10 pairs.

Suppose two doctors are assigned at random to diagnose one person in each pair, so in each pair each person is diagnosed by a different doctor.

Suppose that each doctor reports a vector of symptoms for each patient.  That is, the response for patient $i$ diagnosed by doctor $j$ is a report $x_{ij}=(a,b,c,)^T$ where each element reports the number of instances of condition a, b, or c in patient $i$  like $x_{ij}=(2,5,0)$.

Since the doctors are assigned to patients at random we would expect the average report $x_{.j}=(\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c})^T$ across doctors  to be identical *if* both doctors have the same diagnostic ability.

How do I test the null that both doctors have the same diagnostic ability against the alternative that they differ in some respect?

Comment: I don't quite follow how the diagnoses for the pair of patients $i$ by doctor $j$ could be $(2, \boldsymbol 5,0)$. I can imagine the doctor diagnosing both patients in the pair with a given disease (as for $a$), or neither patient (as for $c$), or only 1 patient w/ disease $k$ (e.g., $b=1$), but I don't get how $b$ can be $\boldsymbol 5$. Can you clarify this? Furthermore, I gather that a given patient can be diagnosed w/ >1 disease, is that correct? Should we assume there is some correlation b/t the probability of the diseases, or are they independent?